# Grid within a Grid moves when I minimize page

Tags: css, css-grid

I hope someone can help me with this, this is my first post and I have been unable to find an answer when trawling the internet forums & w3 etc.

I am learning HTML & CSS and in doing so trying to recreate a random web page from scratch to learn techniques.

In this case, my web page has two final sections, the first of which contains a grid, the second is the footer.

in the current code format, both of these containers move up over the body of text when I minimize the page but look fine when the page is maximized.

My question is, what is causing this shift, and how can I fix it to remain in the correct position. the page I am trying to recreate is: 
https://www.theadventurejunkies.com/best-skiing-snowboarding-blogs/

```css
* {
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 body {
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
}
 .grid {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 100%;
     grid-template-rows: 143px 40px 375px 79px 2300px 362px 76px;
}
 .link-footer {
     border-top: 20px solid rgb(51,51,51);
     background-color: rgb(39,39,39);
     grid-template: 100% / 10% 40% 20% 20% 10%;
     display: grid;
}
 .box-a {
     border: 1px solid white;
     height: 340px;
     color: white;
}
 .box-b {
     border: 1px solid white;
     color: white;
}
 .box-c {
     border: 1px solid white;
     color: white;
}
 .box-d {
     border: 1px solid white;
     color: white;
}
 .box-e {
     border: 1px solid white;
     color: white;
}
 .footer-image{
     width: 80%;
     height: auto;
}
 .footer {
     border: 1px black dotted;
     background-color: rgb(28,29,30);
}
```

```html
<div class="link-footer">
    <div class="box-a">column</div>
    <div class="box-b">
        <img class="footer-image" src="https://adventurejunkies-theadventurejunk.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/SnowSportsFooter.png">
    </div>
    <div class="box-c">column</div>
    <div class="box-d">column</div>
    <div class="box-e">column</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">footer</div>
```

Comment: Not sure I totally understand the issue you are having but I suspect you simply need to apply a `position` property to both items.  I would also suggest that the footer should be included in the grid container as a bottom row spanning all columns.  Then you simply apply `position:absolute` or `position:fixed` with `bottom:0` to the grid container.

If you inspect the page you wish to copy you will see that this organization is how the original designers have done it, albeit using `display: table` instead of `grid`.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I have just taken some time to get my head around this, and used the edited code you provided.  it stuck the footer to the bottom which solved my problem, so thankyou! However the change has prompted other containers on the page to move out of place.  I am considering starting my grid from scratch, now that I understand the full page layout...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not perfect, but should give you a starting point.

```css
* {
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 
 .link-footer {
     border-top: 20px solid rgb(51,51,51);
     background-color: rgb(39,39,39);
     grid-template-columns: minmax(auto 1fr) repeat(4, 1fr) minmax(auto 1fr);
     grid-template-rows: auto auto;
     display: grid;
}
 .box-a {
     border: 1px solid rgb(51,51,51);
     grid-row: 1;
     grid-column: 1;
     color: white;
}
 .box-b {
     border: 1px solid rgb(51,51,51);
     color: white;
     grid-row: 1;
     grid-column: 2 / 4;
}
 .box-c {
     border: 1px solid rgb(51,51,51);
     color: white;
     grid-row: 1;
     grid-column: 4;
}
 .box-d {
     border: 1px solid rgb(51,51,51);
     color: white;
     grid-row: 1;
     grid-column: 5;
}
 .box-e {
     border: 1px solid rgb(51,51,51);
     color: white;
     grid-row: 1;
     grid-column: 6;
}
 .footer-image{
     width: 80%;
     height: auto;
}
 .footer {
     color: white;
     border: 1px black dotted;
     background-color: rgb(28,29,30);
     grid-row: 2;
     grid-column: 1 / 7;
}
```

```html
<div class="link-footer">
    <div class="box-a">left gutter</div>
    <div class="box-b">
        <img class="footer-image" src="https://adventurejunkies-theadventurejunk.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/SnowSportsFooter.png">
    </div>
    <div class="box-c">snow gear</div>
    <div class="box-d">resources</div>
    <div class="box-e">right gutter</div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```